# Possible to Or Laravel Routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, localization, laravel-routing

I’m building a bilingual site in Laravel 4 and my URLs contain a locale identifier. Beyond that, it’s important to have nice looking slugs in the right language. So, let’s say I have a route at which you would find *mugs*. The equivalent in French would be *tasses*.

Currently what I'm doing is

```
Route::get('{locale}/mugs', ['uses' => 'MugsController@index']);
Route::get('{locale}/mugs/{id}', ['uses' => 'MugsController@show']);

Route::get('{locale}/tasses', ['uses' => 'MugsController@index']);
Route::get('{locale}/tasses/{id}', ['uses' => 'MugsController@show']);
```

And a short URL/locale check and redirect in the controller methods that makes sure that the slug is in the right language, so you don't end up with `/fr/mugs`, for example.

This works ok but may get unwieldy since I will have two of each if I make any more routes. For example, I'd have to have both `{locale}/mugs/ceramic/{id}` and `{locale}/tasses/ceramique/{id}`, etc.

Is there a way to do something like `{locale}/mugs|tasses/{id}` in Laravel? Or even check with RegEx?

I know you can check the route parameters with RegEx, but can you check the actual path components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create regex patterns, and do things like:

```
Route::pattern('mugs', 'mugs|tasses');

Route::get('{locale}/{mugs}', ['uses' => 'MugsController@index']);
Route::get('{locale}/{mugs}/{id}', ['uses' => 'MugsController@show']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
Route::get('{locale}/{special}', ['uses' => 'MugsController@show'])->where('special','^(mugs|tasses)$');
```

`special` in this case must be either `mugs` or `tasses`

Comment: But now all his routes will point to `MugsController@show`, his code also points to `MugsController@index`.

Comment: @hebron I haven't noticed that. I've just revmoed this id part